# В чем смысл данных подходов при работе с потоками?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, concurrency

Сейчас я читаю книгу Williams A. C++ Concurrency in Action. Автор предлагает вызывать функцию join() в catch-ветке блока try-catch:

```
void some_func()
{
   // Какая-то функция
}

void f() 
{
    std::thread t(some_func);
    try 
    {
        do_something_in_current_thread();
    }
    catch 
    {
        t.join();
        throw;
    }
    t.join()
}
```

То, что делает данный код мне понятно. Не понятно только зачем? Ведь если у тебя есть намерение вызвать join(), то почему это нельзя сделать сразу?

Comment: Если делать это сразу - то пока не завершится поток, выполнение текущего будет заблокировано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем примере вызывается функция `do_something_in_current_thread();` и если всё выполнено успешно, то ждать окончания потока.

А если произошло исключение в текущем потоке (*в функции `do_something_in_current_thread();`*), то будет ход вызовов деструкторов в стеке всего, в том числе запущенного потока `std::thread t(some_func);`. И вызов деструктора работающего потока вызовет аварийное завершение программы. *(если вы потоку не сделали `detach`)*.

Поэтому, запускаем ловлю исключений, и если оно произошло, то официально ждём завершения потока и после всего данное исключение запускаем снова выполняться с помощью `throw;`.

Comment: А разве не определённый терминейт для программы будет? В MSVS у меня стопроцентный конец всему     ~thread() noexcept {
        if (joinable()) {
            _STD terminate();
        }
    }

да и https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread

Comment: я же уточнил про `joinable` @Никита Самоуков А неопределёнка это уже алгоритм программы будет уже пахать неадекватно.

Comment: Неопределённое поведение это когда никому неизвестно что произойдёт, а тут я вижу 3 варианта: поток не запущен, поток закончил, ещё работает. и во всех 3 случаях поведение вполне определённое.

Comment: добре, подправил @Никита Самоуков